# MUI-DATATABLES onDownload function giving undefined

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions, mui-datatable

Calling a callback function to get values and render it in

```
onDownload: (buildHead, buildBody, columns, data) => {
          if (this.state.isexceldownload) {
            this.callbackMethod((d) => {
              console.log(d);
              let val = `${buildHead(columns)}${buildBody(d)}`.trim();
              console.log(val)
              return val
            });
          }
        }
```

On click, its downloading a CSV file having **undefined** on first cell.

The dataset inside **val** is:

```
"Col-1","Col-2","Col-3","Col-4","Col-5","Col-6","Col-7"
"007","Car","","US","","Matte Black","Available"
"009","Bike","","UK","","Blue","Available"
```

I would like to know, where I am going wrong.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

After manipulating any data you want to change when the file is downloading as CSV, instead of

```
let val = `${buildHead(columns)}${buildBody(d)}`.trim();
console.log(val)
return val
```

try returning this

```
return "\uFEFF" + buildHead(columns) + buildBody(data);
```